# Loop custom post type by taxonomy (Category)

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, loop

I created a custom post type in my function.php of the theme and some a taxonomy for them.
I added 2 categories in my taxonomy (first, second) and added some post in my new custom post.

I want to make a loop that will select from my custom posts only the ones in the first category (Taxonomy)

Or I want a archive that will display all my custom posts, but separated by the taxonomy like
First category: one post, another post
Second Category: this post, next post

Comment: i post a answer here hope this help you.. :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866198/loop-specific-category-of-a-custom-post-type-in-wordpress/46252847#46252847

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the loop starts use [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).
Available [parameters are here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).
Something like this:

```
global $wp_query;
query_posts( array( 
                    'post_type' => 'mycustomname', 
                    'tax_query' => array( 
                                           'relation' => 'AND', 
                                           array( 
                                                  'taxonomy' => 'mytaxonomyname', 
                                                  'field' => 'slug',
                                                  'terms' => array( 
                                                                    'myterm1slug',
                                                                    'myterm2slug' 
                                                                   ) 
                                                ) 
                                        ) 
                  ) 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess these will help you: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Archive_template
and [Custom Taxonomy Displays](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display)
Say you have a taxonomy named 'fiction'. Then your template will be `taxonomy-fiction.php`. In general, `taxonomy-<taxonomy name>.php` is the way to go!